# Unhandled exception when creating new migration with EF 6

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using an Asp.Net Boilerplate template for building a new asp.net core application. When I run the following command

```
dotnet ef migrations add "created_new_BM_entities"
```

The build starts sucessfull without any exception or warning. But then after a while I receive the following exception and the process stops:

> Unhandled exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not
>   invoke tool dotnet-ef.    bei
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.DotnetToolDispatcher.EnsureValidDispatchRecipient(String[]&
>   programArgs, String toolName)    bei
>   Migrator.EF6.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)

Please note that the template is using Entity Framework 6.1.3 and the [tutorial explains](https://www.aspnetzero.com/Documents/Developing-Step-By-Step-Angular#database-migrations) using the **dotnet ef** command. Therefore I guess that I have a problem with my system configuration. But I have no idea where I can start looking for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally we found the answer. The source of the problem is, that I have updated the nuget packages to the latest versions. Therefor it updated also the Migrator.EF6.Tools package from version 1.1.0 to 1.1.1. What I missed after the update was changing a reference entry in the *.csproj-file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Migrator.EF6.Tools" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This entry above had to be changed manualy from version 1.1.0 to version 1.1.1